# Laravel não retorna BelongsTo

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Opa galera possuo duas tabelas uma com nome Produto e outra com nome ProdutoCategoria. Quando vou fazer os relacionamento na models, somente o objeto ProdutoCategoria retorna os produtos, o objeto Produto não retorna categoria.

```
 class ProdutoCateg extends Model
{
    public function produtos(){
        return $this->hasMany('app\Produto');
    }
}



class Produto extends Model
{
    public function categoria(){
        return $this->belongsTo('app\ProdutoCateg');
    }
}


class Fktables extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('produtos', function ($table){
            $table->foreign('id_produto_categs')->references('id')->on('produto_categs');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Se eu fizer

```
use app\ProdutoCateg; 
$c = ProdutoCateg::find(1);
$c->produtos;
```

Funciona agora se for ao contrário não.

```
use app\Produto
$c = Produto::find(1);
$c->categoria;
```

Retorna nulo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neste caso você precisa especificar explicitamente a chave estrangeira na relação, dessa forma:

```
class Produto extends Model
{
    public function categoria(){
        return $this->belongsTo('app\ProdutoCateg', 'id_produto_categs');
    }
}
```

Recomendo que você use as nomeclaturas exatas para seguirem as convenções que o Laravel utiliza, por exemplo, se você possuir um modelo `Product` e cria uma relação com o modelo `ProductCategory` do tipo `belongsTo`, o Laravel automaticamente utiliza a coluna `product_category_id` para fazer essa relação.

Sugiro uma leitura da página relacionada na [documentação oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one), o tópico exato é `Defining The Inverse Of The Relation`.

Comment: Vlw deu certo!!

Comment: Que bom que ajudei @GuilhermeCosta, você pode sinalizar como resposta aceita se este for o caso. Abraços.